# tsdx - import .css - error - PostCSS plugin postcss-modules requires PostCSS 8

Tags: css, postcss, tsdx, rollup-plugin-postcss

- I have created a package using TSDX create .
- I require to use a .css file
- I followed the guide from https://tsdx.io/customization#rollup

```
Error: Error: PostCSS plugin postcss-modules requires PostCSS 8.
```